# Automapper gives null after mapping

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

```
            var objInterview = ServiceManager.InterviewServiceInstance.GetInterview(InterviewID);
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Interview, InterviewViewModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CityName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Cities.CityName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.DesignationName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Designations.DesignationName));
        });

        InterviewViewModel vmInterview = new InterviewViewModel();
        vmInterview = Mapper.Map<Interview, InterviewViewModel>(objInterview);
        return View("Interview", vmInterview);
```

objInterview has values for CityID and DesignationID. But after mapping, I expect to get the CityName and DesignationName in vmInterview. I get null for them. Am I missing something??

Comment: Are you using EntityFramework? Is lazyloading on?

Comment: Yes I am using EntityFramework. If by lazyloading you mean have I declared my navigational properties as virtual then no, its off.

Comment: In that case, you need a way to tell EF to load them, which will depend on how your ServiceInstance handles these properties. In our setup, we pass in `params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[]` and attach them to the `IQueryable<TEntity> query`. Perhaps show a bit more of your ServiceInstance and I may be able to assist further. Essentially though, you need to load Cities and Designations when you retrieve objInterview.